# How to display Coloumn name in WPF ListBox

Tags: c#

I am working WPF I display dataContext into the listbox but I want to display Coloumn name.
How I can do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the list views view mode to be a grid, and setup columns with headers. Something like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Column name here" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DataMemberToBindToColumnGoesHere}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ListView instead, with the view set to a GridView